# How can I enter input in the output of vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How would I enter user text (entered via `cin`) if I build the file using the top right button in the image below?

[image]

Is there a plugin that I have to use to disable the readonly console?

Comment: What about this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole  What is your setting currently?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I prefer the convenience of pressing the button and to launch my program automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, which by default disables (REPL) interactive terminal. To enable it, add this to your vscode json settings:

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

**Or** open ui settings: type "code runner terminal" and check the 
`code-runner: Run In Terminal` option

Next time you will run this code, it will run in the terminal.

Take a look at the configuration section [config](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration)